# Flutter provider is not updating the widget data and showing previous value

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, provider, state-management

There are two Dropdownbuttonformfield, when select service from first dropdownbuttonformfield it calls provider and which calls API to get doctor list who provides that service based on service id.The API is getting called and getting the response correctly but when I tap on second dropdwnfrmfild which is for doctors list it does not updates the doctors list and shows previous doctor list

```
// Define the function to get the list of doctors from the entity
void getListDoc(ListDoctorEntity? entityDoctor) {
  for (int i = 0; i <= entityDoctor!.result.length - 1; i++) {
    doctorList1.add('${entityDoctor.result[i].firstname} ${entityDoctor.result[i].lastname}');
  }
  setState(() {
    doctorList = doctorList1;
  });
  print('doctor list new ++++++++++++++++ --------------$doctorList');
}

// Define the function to get the doctor based on service and update UI
void getDoc(int id, String service, BuildContext context, ListDoctorProvider provider) {
  doctorList = ['Select doctor'];
  doctorIs = 'Select doctor';
  doctorList1 = ['Select doctor'];
  ListDoctorEntity? doctorEntity;
  provider.eitherFailureOrListDoctor(serviceId: id, clientid: clientID);
  doctorEntity = Provider.of<ListDoctorProvider>(context, listen: false).listdoctor;
  provider.eitherFailureOrListDoctor(serviceId: id, clientid: clientID);
  doctorEntity = Provider.of<ListDoctorProvider>(context, listen: false).listdoctor;
  getListDoc(doctorEntity);
}

// Define the structure of the DropdownButtonFormField
Container buildDropdownContainer(String labelText, List<String> items, String value, Function onChangedCallback) {
  return Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.08,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
    child: DropdownButtonFormField(
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
        labelText: labelText,
        labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
        hintText: labelText,
        hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
        errorStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 0.05),
        border: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
        ),
      ),
      items: items.map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
        value: item,
        child: Text(
          item,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
        ),
      )).toList(),
      value: value,
      onChanged: (value) {
        onChangedCallback(value);
        setState(() {
          labelText == 'Service' ? thisservice = value : doctorIs = value;
        });
      },
    ),
  );
}

// Usage of the DropdownButtonFormField
Column(
  children: [
    buildDropdownContainer('Service', servicelist12, thisservice, (value) async {
      var listdoctorprovider = Provider.of<ListDoctorProvider>(context, listen: false);
      for (int i = 0; i <= sList.length - 1; i++) {
        if (sList[i].name == value.toString()) {
          sid = sList[i].id;
          charges.text = sList[i].amount.toString();
          print('service id is===================$sid');
        }
      }
      await getDoc(sid, value.toString(), context, listdoctorprovider);
      serviceChanged = true;
      print('doctor after service --------------$doctorIs');
    }),

    // Conditionally display a SizedBox based on screen orientation
    screenOrientation.toString() == 'Orientation.landscape'
        ? sizedbox
        : const SizedBox(),

    buildDropdownContainer('Select doctor', doctorList, doctorIs, (value) {
      doctorval = value.toString();
      serviceChanged = false;
    }),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Check flutter [Provider exemple](https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple).
You should notifyListeners(); to "refresh" widgets who listen the provider.